# building (maven tycho) eclipse p2repo with dependencies from other updatesites

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tycho

I am building a p2repo (using maven tycho) for the eclipse plugins which I have developed.

My plugins have dependencies with xtext and log4j plugins which are part of other repositories.

With Maven Tycho, I am successful is building p2repo, but unfortunately when I install this in plain eclipse installation, it ends up with an error stating that these plugins couldn't be installed as "org.apache.log4j" , "xtext" dependencies are not found.

> Based on the general eclipse behaviour, I expected that eclipse automatically >installs the required plugins for an update site... but unfortuantely it is not >the case.

**I am not sure if I explicitly need to specify the required external >update sites**

can someone help me out regarding this topic.

Thanks!!

Comment: can you be more specific on what you put on the update site and what not and which other repos where configured in eclipse. and what are the exact error messages you get

Comment: hello Christian, sorry for the delay in replying. In my eclipse plugin, I have a dependency of org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib plugin.  When update-site is built with my plugins -> and if I try to install this in plain eclipse (neon)  -> I see that installation fails as it is not able to find this org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib plugin

Comment: I assume you don’t have the Xtext update site in your target eclipse

Comment: After doing some search on internet, I found that through **associatesites** tag in pom.xml, we can provide the update sites from which dependencies should be resolved during installation '<site>http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/updates/releases/2.10.0/</site> 
<site>http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20170307180635/repository/</site>
<site>http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/updates/releases/2.9.2/</site>'

Comment: when I specify these update sites in the p2repo plugin pom.xml, it is taking quite long time to install the built "p2repo" (created from my eclipse plugins) in new eclipse ide. *I am looking for a way to only add specific features as a part of associateSites*

Comment: Why don’t you then include all features you need to the repo?

Comment: i am new to this eclipse - maven world. i will be glad if you can share me an example regarding this ..Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: I don’t have any example at hand. But you can simply add more than one feature to your category xml file or add includeded features to your feature xml

Comment: ok *Thanks* for this info.I will give a try